# JS/jQueryでtableの特定のクラス名がついた行のみ表示する際の高速化

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>セル</td>
    <td>セル</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="active">
    <td>セル</td>
    <td>セル</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>セル</td>
    <td>セル</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

このようなHTML構造のテーブルがあります。`tr` 要素に `class="active"` がついている行のみ表示したいとき、愚直にやると以下のようなコードになると思います。

```
// 一旦全部非表示
$('table tr').hide();

// activeがついているtr要素のみ表示
$('table tr[class="active"]').show();
```

これが少ない行数のtableならパッと表示されるのですが、10000行を超えるテーブルになると動作がもっさりしてしまいます。少しでも高速化する方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まあCSSでやるのが速いのは言うまでもないですが、`show()` を使わないだけでも相当速くなるようです。

```js
var table = $('table');
var row = ('<tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>');
var row_active = ('<tr class="active"><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>');

var src = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
 src += (i % 2 ? row : row_active);
table.html(src);

$('div')
.append($('<button>').text('reset').click(function(){
 $('table').removeClass('filter');
  $('table tr').each(function(){this.style.display=null;});
}))
.append($('<button>').text('hide/show').click(function(){
  $('table tr').hide();
  $('table tr[class="active"]').show();
}))
.append($('<button>').text('non jQuery').click(function(){
 $('table tr').each(function() {
   this.style.display = $(this).hasClass("active") ? null : "none";
  });
}))
.append($('<button>').text('addClass').click(function(){
  $('table').addClass('filter');
}));
```

```css
body { font-size: 10px; }
.active { color: red }
.filter tr:not(.active) { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><table></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSSで実現すると高速だと思われます。`active` ではない `tr` を不可視にすれば良いです。

動的に可視状態を切り替えるサンプルを作りました。

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.targettable').classList.add('showactiveonly');
});
```

```css
.targettable .active {
  background: lime;
}

.targettable.showactiveonly tr:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>アクティブ行のみ表示</button>
<table class="targettable">
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr class="active"><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
<tr><td>cell<td>cell<td>cell</tr>
</table>
```